# Docusaurus website GitHub pages deploy doesn't work for organisations

Tags: deployment, documentation, github-pages, docusaurus

When I completed to design of our docs website with Docusaurus I wanted to deploy it to GitHub pages. In normally this is no hard. I need to change a few things in docusaurus.config.js and use "GITHUB_USER= yarn deploy" command. However this repo isn't in the my GitHub profile. It's in the organisation GitHub profile of our company. I have permission for push but when I tried to "GITHUB_USER= yarn deploy" command I got "website live at [https://ourOrganisationGithubUsername.github.io/ourProjectName/"](https://ourOrganisationGithubUsername.github.io/ourProjectName/%22) message. Actually it's normal cause I have watched some videos about that and they got same message but I try to see the website I get 404 error.

What should I do now ?

Note: I have tried to "GITHUB_USER= yarn deploy" command with my own GitHub username (as I said before I have permission for push.). Do I have to use our organisation username ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried deploy with my coworker's username who is an admin on our company's Github account. It works well then I could deploy after first publish with my own username. When I gave the username of our company, it asked me for the password of the company account. I think it isn't a healty solution.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same issue! My repository was private, so I made the repository public, and the Issue was solved.